# LaTeX: problem with table captions when using the subfig package

Tags: beamer

I run Arch Linux with texlive version 2019.52579-1. When I compile the LaTeX (Beamer) code below the table caption is "Figure: A simple table." That is, it includes "Figure:" instead of "Table:". The problem does not occur when the subfig package is not used. Suggestions (other than removing the subfig package) are welcome. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A simple frame}

\begin{table} 
\caption{A simple table.}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
a & b \\
c & d \\        
\hline                 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show the `.log` as well? I can't replicate your issue.